# How to calculate the strength of a silicon joint in an aquarium?

Tags: pressure, stress-strain

I'm building an aquarium, and i'm trying to answer the question "Will it catastrophically fail?" by reading the datasheet of the Silicon glue and doing a bit of calculation for worst-case scenario.

the datasheet gives

- the tensile strenght $TS$, given in $\frac{N}{mm^2}$
- the tearing resistance $TR$, given in percentage
- the E module 100% (elongation module?), given again in $\frac{N}{mm^2}$

These measurements are given following the DIN 53 504 standard.

The front glass of the aquarium is glued in place by 3 strips of silicon, so i thought that to not fail, the tensile strenght along all the area of the silicon has to be greater than the force of the water along the glass.

given $a, b, c : height, width, profondity$ of a glass panel, the expression

$$ TS(2ac + bc) - \int_0^agbh\,\mathrm{d}h$$
must be positive, right?

the formula calculates the force exerted by the three glued sides and subtracts the integral of water pressure along the area of the glass panel.

any hints on how to use the other two parameters of the silicon glue, are apreciated

Comment: Not quite that easy -- the pressure will be maximum at the bottom of the tank, so the most likely place for a leak (blowing out the silicone) is along that joint. You may have to calculate the combination of silicone "stretching" and the force to bow the glass plate enough to cause the silicone to pull free of the glass.  Tho' I guess that doesn't count as "catastrophic", to be fair.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, right now a lot of simplifying assumptions are made for this ballpark estimation. but the case of water pushing against silicon seems interesting enough to calculate, but i'm not sure how